# Laravel - How to query a chain of one-to-many relationship to one-to-one relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

The end goal is to get a collection of Albums from a User. However there is another model between them: Albums.

```
$user->artists()->get(); //this will retrieve a collection of artists from a particular user

$user->artists()->albums()->get() //results in: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::riderNegotiation()
```

My models aren't actually called this but for simplicities sake this is what I'm calling them. So changing the database structure is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried using dynamic properties?  Get rid of the parentheses in your second example and it should work.  In fact, you can remove the `get` at the end as well.

Comment: I don't get the question. If you want to get a collection of artists from a user, won't the first line be the answer already?

Comment: @JetLaggy sorry, typo. I want the collection of Albums per User.

Answer (score 2):

You can query relations and data will be injected in `$user` instance:

```
// if you already have an instance
$user->load('artists.albums');
```

or

```
// get a user instance with related data 
$user = User::with('artists.albums')->find($id);
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on how to access the albums from the $user after injecting them with the code above. My returned error is that there is no method 'albums'. I should mention that in my case, artists and albums have a one to one relationship